# Does the Bhagavad Gita actually have 745 shlokas?

Tags: mahabharata, bhagavad-gita

Does the Bhagavad Gita really have 745 shlokas?

Even Chapter 43, shloka 4 of the Bhishma Parva of the Mahabharata says that the Gita has 745 slokas: [image]

> षट्शतानि सविंशानि क्ष्लोकानां प्राह केशवः ।
> अर्जुनः सप्तपञ्चाशत्‌ सप्तषष्टिं तु संजयः ॥
> घृतराष्ट्रः क्ष्लोकमेकं गीताया मानमुच्यते ।

> This Gita has 620 Shlokas said by Lord ShriKrishna. 57 shlokas said by Arjuna, 67 shlokas said by Sanjay and 1 shloka said by Dhritarashtra.

Answer (score 5):

In his Introduction, pages xvii-xviii, to his translation of the *Bhagavad Gita* (*Bhagavad Gita with the commentary of Sankaracarya*), Swami Gambhirananda writes:

> According to the recension of the *Gita* commented on by Sankaracharya, the number of verses is 700. But there is evidence to show that some old manuscripts had 745. The *Gita* published in Srinigar, Kashmir, with the annotation of Abhinavaguptacarya, contains the same number of verses. Other manuscripts have been discovered with variations both in the number of verses and in the readings. Pusalker is of the opinion that 'the additional stanzas effect no material addition; nor do they create any differences in the teaching or argument.' (*Studies in Epics and Puranas*, p. 144.) He further remarks that 'Sankaracarya's testimony for the text of the *Bhagavadgita* is earlier than that of any other MS or commentator.' (ibid. p 147.) However that may be, after Sankaracarya wrote his Commentary, the *Gita* has taken a definite form with 700 verses, so far as least the general public is concerned.

Comment: But what about Mahabharata sloka

Answer (score 5):

No, it doesn't. The verse you quoted and a whole bunch of other verses following the Bhagavad-gītā upa-parva of Bhīṣma Parva are not present in [BORI's Critical Edition (CE) of the Mahābhārata](http://www.bori.ac.in/mahabharata_project.html), so, it must be a late addition to the text.

On [GRETIL's website](http://gretil.sub.uni-goettingen.de/gretil/1_sanskr/2_epic/mbh/mbh_06_u.htm), which hosts the CE, you can see the verse prefixed with an asterisk (`*`) meaning it did not make it to the CE:

> 06,040.074   saṃjaya uvāca
> 06,040.074a  ity ahaṃ vāsudevasya pārthasya ca mahātmanaḥ
> 06,040.074c  saṃvādam imam aśrauṣam adbhutaṃ romaharṣaṇam
> 06,040.075a  vyāsaprasādāc chrutavān etad guhyam ahaṃ param
> 06,040.075c  yogaṃ yogeśvarāt kṛṣṇāt sākṣāt kathayataḥ svayam
> 06,040.076a  rājan saṃsmṛtya saṃsmṛtya saṃvādam imam adbhutam
> 06,040.076c  keśavārjunayoḥ puṇyaṃ hṛṣyāmi ca muhur muhuḥ
> 06,040.077a  tac ca saṃsmṛtya saṃsmṛtya rūpam atyadbhutaṃ hareḥ
> 06,040.077c  vismayo me mahān rājan hṛṣyāmi ca punaḥ punaḥ
> 06,040.078a  yatra yogeśvaraḥ kṛṣṇo yatra pārtho dhanurdharaḥ
> 06,040.078c  tatra śrīr vijayo bhūtir dhruvā nītir matir mama
>
> 06,040.078d`*`0111_01  bhagavadbhaktiyuktasya tatprasādātmabodhataḥ
> 06,040.078d`*`0111_02  sukhaṃ bandhavimuktiḥ syād iti gītārthasaṃgrahaḥ
> 06,040.078d`*`0112_01  **ṣaṭ śatāni saviṃśāni ślokānāṃ prāha keśavaḥ**
> 06,040.078d`*`0112_02  **arjunaḥ saptapañcāśat saptaṣaṣṭis tu saṃjayaḥ**
> 06,040.078d`*`0112_03  **dhṛtarāṣṭraḥ ślokam ekaṃ gītāyā mānam ucyate**
> 06,040.078d`*`0113_00  vaiśaṃpāyana uvāca
> 06,040.078d`*`0113_01  gītā sugītā kartavyā kim anyaiḥ śāstravistaraiḥ
> 06,040.078d`*`0113_02  yā ceyaṃ padmanābhasya mukhapadmād viniḥsṛtā
> 06,040.078d`*`0113_03  sarvaśāstramayī gītā sarvadevamayo hariḥ
> 06,040.078d`*`0113_04  sarvatīrthamayī gaṅgā sarvavedamayo manuḥ
> 06,040.078d`*`0113_05  gaṅgā gītā ca gāyatrī govindeti hṛdi sthite
> 06,040.078d`*`0113_06  caturgakārasaṃyukte punarjanma na vidyate
> 06,040.078d`*`0114_01  bhāratāmṛtasarvasvagītāyā mathitasya ca
> 06,040.078d`*`0114_02  sāram uddhṛtya kṛṣṇena arjunasya mukhe hutam
>
> 06,041.001   saṃjaya uvāca
> 06,041.001a  tato dhanaṃjayaṃ dṛṣṭvā bāṇagāṇḍīvadhāriṇam
> 06,041.001c  punar eva mahānādaṃ vyasṛjanta mahārathāḥ

So, if you go with the Critical Edition, the Gītā has exactly 700 verses. It begins at Chapter 23 of Bhīṣma Parva and ends at Ch. 40.

> **Section Sixty-Three**
>
> **Bhagavad Gita Parva**
>
> This parva has 994 shlokas and twenty seven chapters.
>
> Chapter 874 (14): 13 shlokas 
> Chapter 875 (15): 75 shlokas 
> Chapter 876 (16): 46 shlokas 
> Chapter 877 (17): 39 shlokas 
> Chapter 878 (18): 18 shlokas 
> Chapter 879 (19): 44 shlokas 
> Chapter 880 (20): 20 shlokas 
> Chapter 881 (21): 17 shlokas 
> Chapter 882 (22): 22 shlokas 
> **Chapter 883 (23): 47 shlokas**   `[BG STARTS HERE]` 
> Chapter 884 (24): 72 shlokas 
> Chapter 885 (25): 43 shlokas 
> Chapter 886 (26): 42 shlokas 
> Chapter 887 (27): 29 shlokas 
> Chapter 888 (28): 47 shlokas 
> Chapter 889 (29): 30 shlokas 
> Chapter 890 (30): 28 shlokas 
> Chapter 891 (31): 34 shlokas 
> Chapter 892 (32): 42 shlokas 
> Chapter 893 (33): 55 shlokas 
> Chapter 894 (34): 20 shlokas 
> Chapter 895 (35): 34 shlokas 
> Chapter 896 (36): 27 shlokas 
> Chapter 897 (37): 20 shlokas 
> Chapter 898 (38): 24 shlokas 
> Chapter 899 (39): 28 shlokas 
> **Chapter 900 (40): 78 shlokas**  `[BG ENDS HERE]`
>
> This section is so named because it includes the Song Celestial or the
> Bhagavad Gita, the teachings of Krishna to Arjuna. The section begins
> with the dramatic news that Bhishma has been killed. When Sanjaya tells
> Dhritarashtra this, Dhritarashtra (and the reader) is astounded, wishing
> to know how this came to be. After a description of the arrangements for
> war, the rest of this section is the Bhagavad Gita.
>
> ([Debroy, Bibek. The Mahabharata: Volume 5](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/B06XYKLSZP))

Comment: Very nice answer sir 

Answer (score 3):

The most widely used Gita is the one which was commented by Shankaracharya and is probably the oldest and has 700 verses. Even if we consider 745 Shlokas for the sake of argument, Majority essence of Gita is already covered in 700 Shlokas and rest Shlokas hardly give any additional meaning or change context. I will just quote few Indologists now.

Indologist Bhattacharya in his "Original Bhagavadgita Complete with 745 Verses" on page 21-22 says -

> The message conveyed by Bhagavadgita is authentic and not very much
> different from original version with 745 verses except that the later
> has missing verses and there are some minor alterations in words here
> and there.

Dr Pusalker in his work "Studies in Epics and Puranas", on page 144 says -

> It is indeed curios how the Bhagavad-Gita presents such a relatively
> fixed consistent text without any noteworthy variation for the last
> 1200 years. The current text contains 700 stanzas, there being to
> other texts with 714 and 745 stanzas. The additional stanzas affect no
> material addition; nor do they create any difference in the teaching
> or add any new topic or argument.

Scholar Upadhyaya in his work of 1998 page 10-122 says -

> Variant manuscripts of the Gita have been found on Indian
> subcontinent. Unlike enormous variations in remaining sections of
> surviving Mahabharata manuscripts, the Gita manuscripts show only
> minor variations and meaning is the same.

Robert N Minor in his "Bhagavadgita : An Exegetical Commentary", 1982 says -

> The current text of Bhagavad Gita is well preserved with relatively
> few variant readings and none quite serious. This is remarkable in
> light of numerous variants for the remainder of the Mahabharata, some
> of which are serious. Secondary insertions are found in individual
> manuscripts of Gita but they are clearly secondary. The number of
> Stanzas in Gita is 700, a number conformed by Shankara and possibly
> deliberatly chosen to prevent interpolations.

TMP Mahadevan in his "Original Bhagavad Gita" says -

> Unless clear and unmistakable evidences are forthcoming, there is no
> justification for regarding any verse of Gita as interpolation.

SC Roy in his "The Bhagavadgita and Modern Scholarship", 1941 says -

> The text of the Gita has remained substantially unaltered in spite of
> numberless interpolations that have taken place in other portions of
> Mahabharata and hence theory of Interpolation in Gita is without any
> foundation.

The questioner showed that Mahabharata at one time mentions that Gita has 745 Verses. But this verse wasn't found in the critical edition of Mahabharata.

Lin Yutang in his work of 1964, in page 45-46 criticizes some of western bias and criticism of Gita. He says -

> Any attempt by Western critics to separate serval strands of belief
> from one another in the song and restore the original text is bound to
> be foolish and ridiculous. Certain scholars have attempted foolish
> task of determining Gita's original composition.