Where in Mahabharatha the following verse about the total number of Shlokas in Gita is found?
Bhagavad Gita, though a Vedantic text, commented by Abhinavagupta in light of Kashmir Shaivism. One salient feature of his commentary is that it has many additional verses. Boris Marjanovic who translated his commentary into English, mentioned the following:

At the outset I want to point out that this translation of the Gita
text will differ in places from other English translations. The reason
for this is that the Kashmiri recension of the Bhagavad Gita used by
Abhinavagupta in his commentary differs from other available
recensions. First of all, the Kashmiri recension contains fifteen
additional verses. Some of the more interesting additional verses can
be found in Chapter 2, verses 11 and 50, and in Chapter 3, verses
38-42. In addition to that, a great number of verses found in the
Kashmiri recension partly differ from the vulgate or the critical
editions.

This website mentions one verse from Mahabharata citing the number of verses of Bhagavad Gita:

Most of the commentaries are based on recension of the Gita containing
700 verses but some Kashmiri commentators have adopted slightly
variant recension known as Kashmiri Recension as per the text of
Mahabharata –

“Shatshatani Savimshani Shlokanam Praha Keshvah, Arjuna
Saptpanchashat Saptshashtimch Sanjayah, Dhritrashtra Shlokam Ekam
Gitaya Manam Uchatey.” (Bhishma Parva, Chapter 43, Verse 4)
wherein
it is described that total number of verses of the Gita should be 745,
out of which 620 are spoken by Krishna, 57 by Arjuna, 67 by Sanjay and
1 by Dhritrashtra.


I am interested to locate the highlighted verse in bold. I searched in Sanskrit version available online for the above verse which says there are 745 verses in Bhagavad Gita, however I couldn't able to find in Bhishma Parva Chapter 43.

This verse is found in the Mahabharata by Gita Press (Volume 3) in Sanskrit and Hindi.
The section which you've quoted is correct i.e., Bhishma Parva Chapter 43 Verse 4.


So even we have variance in manuscripts of prastanatrayi too? I always thought Upanishads, Brahma sutras and Bhagavad Gita are in the same form right from the beginning

These answers might be worth taking a look at specifically on the Bhagavad Gita:
https://hinduism.stackexchange.com/questions/262/does-the-gita-have-any-apocrypha
https://hinduism.stackexchange.com/questions/45023/does-the-bhagavad-gita-actually-have-745-shlokas
